# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button

Tags: android

Hi a few days ago i ran my android application in my cell phone which has the android version 9 ,everything was working perfectly unfortunately he is out of order since then  , i can't use it anymore . Now i'm trying to run my app in another phone which has the android version 5 but it's not working . Not that i didn't change the code .
Any recommendations ? 
Thank you

Here is the error from Logcat :

```
Process: com.example.bachmaps, PID: 1887
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bachmaps/com.example.bachmaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.bachmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.bachmaps:drawable/admin" (7f070056)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070056 a=-1 r=0x7f070056}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4017)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3779)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1043)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:115)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.bachmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: post relevant XML layout

Comment: can you explain to me what it is please ?

Comment: It would seem that your `admin` drawable is not available for that particular Android version. That is, for example, it's in a folder that's named something like `res/drawable-v23/`, while Android 5 is API level 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the error was, I moved all my drawable content from drawable(v24) to drawable